# Checkboard artifact appears and scrolling stops when changing value of combobox

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

1. **Phone**:  Samsung Galaxy S
2. **Firmware**:  2.3.5
3. **Build number:**  GINGERBREAD.UCKK4 Kernel:  2.6.35.7-I897UCKK4-CL614489
4. **Browser:**     Standard Android Browser

I have a simple html form that, once I change the value of a combobox, I can no longer scroll vertically and the form becomes unusable.

In addition, a strange black & white checkerboard pattern appears at the top and bottom of my form.

[Here is a video to demonstrate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oC8fjgqkHAs).  It shows the form scrolling up and down normally.  Then, I change the value and then the checkerboard pattern appears.

**NOTE**:  If I turn the display off, then turn it back on, the form returns to normal.

Is there anything wrong in my html that would cause this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Paleo Meal</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=
  "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type=
  "text/javascript">
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Paleo Meal</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <div id="_addMealFrame" data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" data-theme="a"
      data-collapsed="false">
        <h3 data-theme="d" id="_mealFrameText">Meal Details</h3>

        <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="_profileForm" data-ajax=
        "false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="_mealDate">Date:</label><input type="text" name="meal_date"
            value="01/14/13" id="_mealDate" autocomplete="off" />
          </div>

          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="_mealTime" class="select">Meal Time:</label><select name=
            "meal_time" id="_mealTime">
              <option value="0">
                12 am
              </option>

              <option value="1">
                1 am
              </option>

              <option value="23">
                11pm
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="_mealType" class="select">Meal Type:</label><select name=
            "meal_type_id" id="_mealType">
              <option value="1">
                Breakfast
              </option>

              <option value="2">
                Lunch
              </option>

              <option value="3">
                Dinner
              </option>

              <option value="4">
                Snack
              </option>

              <option value="5">
                Other
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <a href="" id="_cancel" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-inline=
            "true">Cancel</a><button name="" type="submit" id="_submit" class=
            "ui-btn-hidden" value="Save" aria-disabled="false" data-inline="true"
            data-theme="b"></button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```